# Scroll never appears in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scroll, listbox

```
    <Grid>  
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <ListView  Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HistoryList, Mode=OneWay}"  Name="leftPanelScrollViewer" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Border Background="{Binding Background}" Tag="{Binding Id}" ContextMenuOpening="FrameworkElement_OnContextMenuOpening" ContextMenuClosing="FrameworkElement_OnContextMenuClosing" ContextMenuService.HasDropShadow="True" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom" ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=PersonNameHistoryItem}"  Padding="10 80" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="0" Margin="5,0,5,5" MouseLeftButtonUp="Item_OnMouseDown">
                                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition  />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="44" Height="44" Source="/Size.WPF;component/Assets/default-avatar.png" />
        ...
                                               </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

I have this code in WPF App.

Problem - scroll never appears. Instead of adding scroll `ListView` make Height bigger.

The same with `ListBox`.

*When I don't need scroll it looks like*  **and**      *When I need scroll it looks like*

[image]  [image]

---

In what wrapped `ListBox` : `Page` > `Grid` (

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="90"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="780" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

) > `Grid` (`Grid.RowSpan="3"`)> `Border` > `Grid` (`<RowDefinition Height="*" />`) > `ListView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably got the grid inside a stack panel or some other control that's unbound in size.

Stack panels grow to what ever size their content needs.

You need to either restrict the maximum size of the stack panel or remove it altogether.

Once you've done that the scrollbar should appear.

Comment: After removing `StackPanel` from `ItemTemplate` scroll still is disappeared :(

Comment: @demo - sorry. I misread the code. What I meant was that you've probably got a stack panel outside the grid.

Comment: I added all control in what ListBox is wrapper. Hope all there is understanding

Comment: And problem is in Last Row of First Grid, where I set `Height` as `Auto`